# glDrawArrays() doesn't work

Tags: opengl

I tried render simple triangle using glVertexPointer, glColorPointer and glDrawArrays, but it still doesn't work. There is also version with glBegin and it works, so there isn't fault in vertices.

```
void GlWindow::paintGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslated(0,-0.5,-1.0);

    GLfloat object[] = {
        -length/5, 0.0, 0.0,
        length/5, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    };

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    };


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, object);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);


    /*
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-length/5, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(length/5, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    */
    glFlush();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last argument to glDrawArrays is the number of vertices. So in this case you should specify 3, not 1.

Comment: oh i thought it's number of elements, so number of triangles in this case. Thx.

Comment: @Krab: Even if it were the number of elements (as OpenGL uses the term), it would still be 3. OpenGL defines elements in this context to mean indices. Triangles are a type of primitive, no draw command takes the number of primitives.